# Difficult to understand the particularly with respect to inputs

Tags: c, algorithm, math, logic

`Question`
In a Multinational company employees are ordered to seat according to their height in a line. they always choose their positions randomly to displeasure their manager. one evening, the employee learn that their strict manager has secretly recorded their seating positions from that morning, and that he will be checking their positions in the next morning to make sure they are exactly the same.

Each employee only remember one thing from that morning: the number of people to his left that were teller then him.

there are n employees, each with a different height between 1 to n. using this information you must reconstruct the seating arrangement from that morning.

you are given a int[], the ith element of which represents the number of taller employees to the left of the employee with height i (where i is a 1-based index). Return a int[] containing the heights of the employees from left to right in the line.

Note: The input is guaranteed to produce a valid and unique output.

Inputs Specifications: 
your function should accept the fallowing inputs: 
Input 1: n
Input 2: An array(left[]) of n integers

Output Specifications: 
you need to return the int [] containing the heights of the employees from left to right in the line.

```
Example : 
Input: 
input 1: 4 
input 2: {2,1,1,0} 

Output: {4,2,1,3} 

Explanation: 
Employee of height 1 remembered there were 2 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 2 remembered there were 1 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 3 remembered there were 1 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 4 remembered there were no employees taller than him to his left.
```

the original order from left to right must have been 4,2,1,3. this ordering satisfies all four conditions. For example, there are exactly two employees to the left of the employees with height 1 that are taller then him(heights 4 and 2). A different ordering,like `4,3,1,2`, satisfies some, but not all of the four conditions. `in this incorrect ordering, there are two employees to the left of employee with height 2 that are taller then him(height 4 and 3), but input states that there was only one.`

`My understanding:`
If I have understood the question correctly the,

```
Input1 = 4 (Value of n is 4)
Input2 = {2, 1, 1, 0}, 
One of the output would be 4 2 1 3
```

This means that,

```
The Employee1 has height 1 and there were 2 people left to him [4 2]
The Employee2 has height 2 and there was 1 people left to him [4]
The Employee3 has height 3 and there was 1 people left to him [1] but how? height 3 is taller than 1
The Employee4 has height 4 and there was 0 people left to him[No one is left of 4]
```

So one ordering is `4 2 1 3` which satisfies to our condition.

But when we try with `4 3 1 2`, this also satisfies all the conditions. But I could not able to understand from the explanation that, `in this incorrect ordering, there are two employees to the left of employee with height 2 that are taller then him(height 4 and 3), but input states that there was only one.`
but the input states that, there 2 employees left to him not one...
I am really confused with the questions explanation.
Please help me if I am going wrong anywhere.
Because for me `4 3 2 1` satisfies all conditions

2. The Employee3 has height 3 and there was 1 people left to him [1]; Employee3 is taller than Employee1, so how he can be at the end of the array and if we see who is the tallest person left to Employee3?

Please help me understanding this question. I will code my logic for this once I understand this.

1. What does the question mean with 
   `you are given a int[], the ith element of which represents the number of taller employees to the left of the employee with height i`
2. Why `4 3 1 2` sequence is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q.1) What does the question mean with
>
> you are given a int[], the ith element of which represents the number
>   of taller employees to the left of the employee with height i

Let's try to understand it from the example you have given

```
Example : 
Input: 
input 1: 4 
input 2: {2,1,1,0}
```

And the corresponding explanation that was accompanied by it -

```
Explanation: 
Employee of height 1 remembered there were 2 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 2 remembered there were 1 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 3 remembered there were 1 employees taller than him to his left. 
Employee of height 4 remembered there were no employees taller than him to his left.
```

Here, input 2 is an 1-based indexed array. The indexes correspond to employee height. The values correspond to how many taller employees did he remember to his left. First value of the array is 2. It means employee who has height 1 remembered that there were 2 employees taller than him to his left. Similarly, second value 1 means employee who is of height 2 remembered that there was 1 employee taller than him to his left. Third value 1 means the employee whose height is 3 remembered that there was 1 employee taller than him to his left. Finally the 4th and largest indexed value is 0. That means the tallest employee who in this case is of height 4 remembered that there were no employees taller than him to his left. I basically told the same thing written in the explanation. This array is basically: from the shortest employee (height 1) to the tallest employee (here height 4) telling you the number of taller employees they remembered to their left.

> Q.2) Why `4 3 1 2` sequence is not possible?

The output should be the heights of the employees in their original order. In `4 3 1 2` output you are placing the employee who is of height 2 to the right most place. From his position he would see 2 people (employee with height 4 and employee with height 3) taller than him to his left. But according to the input he remembered there was 1 employee taller than him to his left. Hence, `4 3 1 2` can not be the original order.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understand the question

```
The Employee3 has height 3 and there was 1 people left to him [1] but how? height 3 is taller than 1
```

Your above statement isn't correct. The questions say `How many people in your left side is taller than i number`

```
Why 4 3 1 2 sequence is not possible?
```

This isn't valid sequence as **1** has two number greater than **1** in the left

Hope it helps you

Comment: There was a typo. It was not `4 3 2 1`, I changed it to `4 3 1 2`

Comment: It is also not valid as problem description 2 has two person in the left taller taller than 2

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could write the code for the same

```
# input1 n = no. of employees 4
# input2 array of n elements  {2, 1, 1, 0}
# Output [4, 2, 1, 3]
# 0 [2, 1, 1, 0] [4, 2, 1, 3]
# 1 [2, 1, 1, 0] [4, 2, 1, 3]
# 2 [2, 1, 1, 0] [4, 2, 1, 3]
# 3 [2, 1, 1, 0] [4, 2, 1, 3]

import copy


def findLogic(temp, input2):
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(zip(temp, input2)):
        count = 0
        if i == 0:
            countList = []
        j = i + 1
        #print(i, temp, input2)
        if j in input2:
            #print(i, temp, input2, input2.index(j))
            for l in range(input2.index(j), -1, -1):
                if l >= 0 and j <= (len(input2)-1):
                    if j < input2[l]:
                        count += 1
            countList.append(count)
            if countList == temp:
                #print(input2)
                print("{", end="")
                for i in input2:
                    print(i, end="")
                    if input2.index(i) != len(input2) - 1:
                        print(",", end="")
                print("}", end="")
                return 1

def PlaceNumbs(input2, l, r, temp):
    if l == r:
        if findLogic(temp, input2):
            return
    for i in range(l, r):
        input2[l], input2[i] = input2[i], input2[l]
        PlaceNumbs(input2, l + 1, r, temp)
        input2[l], input2[i] = input2[i], input2[l]

#def FinalOrder(n, input2):
def uniqueValue(input1,input2):
    n = input1
    temp = copy.deepcopy(input2)
    input3 = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        input3.append(int(i))
    PlaceNumbs(input3, 0, n, temp)

uniqueValue(4, [2, 1, 1, 0])
print("\n")
uniqueValue(8, [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to return the height of the employees in a order such that it satisfy the conditions given in the array.

> For instance:
>
> The first element in the array denotes the number of greater employee
>   on the left of the employee having height equals to 1. Similarly the
>   second element denotes that number of greater employees on the left of
>   the employee having height equals to 2 and so on.

Here goes my code in c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int* uniqueValue(int input1,int input2[])
{
    int *out = new int[input1];
     int i,j,k, count;


     for(i=0; i<input1; i++)
         out[i] = input1;


     for(i=0; i< (input1-1); i++)
     {
         count = 0;

         for(j=0; j< (input1-1); j++)
         {
             if(out[j] > (i+1))
                 count++;
             if(count == input2[i])
             {
                 for(k = j+1; k<input1; k++)
                     if(out[k] == input1)
                     {
                         out[k] = i+1;
                         break;
                     }
                 break;
             }
             else if(count > input2[i])
             {
                 for(k = j; k<input1; k++)
                     if(out[k] == input1)
                     {
                         out[k] = i+1;
                         break;
                     }
                 break;
             }
         }
     }

     return out;
 }
```